# How can I adjust the position of shadow according to the light source in 3d viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

Although I adjusted the position of light in 3d viewport, the position of shadow did not change accordingly.

I want the position of shadow catch up with the change of light position in 3d viewport. (not in rendered mode)

Would you please help me?

Comment: Hi. I think you should have shadow here. Could you upload the blend file? Please use this link to to it https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon Well... I guess that you think problem a little difficult. Not in rendered mode(ex: solid mode or look dev mode) I want the shadow of object(ex:cube) change it's position according to change of the position of light source like in rendered mode.

Comment: I don't think solid view is intended to manage light shadows. Though, you have a "world space lightning" option that can give a one direction light source.

Comment: @lemon Ok thank you good man.